# how to receive return value from a methord into a variable in pyqt5?

Tags: pyqt5

i have written my code to send a value to a method,
 i.e

```
    b = "tp send"
    a = self.sendnprint.clicked.connect(lambda: self.CBautofill(b))
    print(a)
```

and then method be like this

```
 def CBautofill(self,a10):
    print(a10)
    appppppp = "to receive"
    return(appppppp)
```

but i actually doesn't receive any error but the result are not as per the exception as well as i think its receiving the null value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons for which you're not getting what you're looking for.

First of all, a lambda declaration doesn't `return` a result, but the lambda function itself:

```py
In [1]: a = lambda x: x * 5

In [2]: print(a)
<function <lambda> at 0xb5d6a95c>

In [3]: print(a(5))
25
```

Then, a `signal -> slot` connection is just a function that *connect* a signal to a slot (a function/method) and returns `None`.

```py
        # ...
        b = "tp send"
        self.sendnprint.clicked.connect(lambda: self.getResult(b))

    def getResult(self, value):
        print(self.CBautofill(value))

    def CBautofill(self,a10):
        print(a10)
        appppppp = "to receive"
        return(appppppp)
```

Comment: THANKS BUDDY I GOT IT